# Why cant i buy Skylanders Imaginators (a PS Now game)?

Tags: psn, skylanders

I tried to buy Skylanders Imaginators for the ps4 but there is no buy or purchase option on the screen. What do I do to get it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no digital version of "Skylanders Imaginators" on any platform, because it requires special hardware to play. You must buy a physical copy.